# Internet explorer some elements dont work

Tags: internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer some elements don't work: Chat, Contact, Tutorial, Survey. These elements work in Firefox and Chrome.
http://hotelpedia.si is the website.
I have this code in the footer. I don't understand why this would cause some elements not to load in Internet Explorer.

```
{if $is_ie_browser}
<!--[if lt IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/css/ie.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="{$smarty.const.DOMAIN}/css/ie_7.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
{/if}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code checks to see if internet explorer is less than internet explorer 9 and if so display one css. otherwise if internet explorer 7 then use the other css. If you are using internet explorer 10 then you likely do not have a css page (atleast from what we can see in the code that you posted. change that second line to be "if lt IE10" or add a line that uses greater than equal 8 "gte"

Comment: Doe this have to do some elements are not showing ? As google analytics work.
Also is possible to delay 2 codes in that files ? now it show to javascript pop up's at same time. I want to set it after this survey is finished or minimized then it lunch another code.

Comment: First check which versions of IE that it is not working in, my assumption is that it is not working in internet explorer 10. If that is your issue then if you do not have the proper css applied to your tags then that would cause the elements to not show up correctly. I am unclear on what you mean by "delay" two codes. but I think what you want to do is change your css once an event happens. Hopefully this will help you: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp Basically you will have an event listener in javascript that will trigger a javascript function to change your css.

Comment: I don't need .css for that i even don't know how this site is coded :( is based on PROCMS http://www.pro-cms.net/
I just inputed javascript code (so no div)
This is code i put in footer.
http://pastebin.com/KjQafftz